# Silent printing from laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf, printing

I have developed a system where i need to generate pdfs using this package of laravel https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Now client is looking for silent printing feature so that user don't see any printing preview page and printer can get command from one click on button.

I didn't find any help yet. Please guide if its possible in laravel or not.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is this function `printer_list` doing? Show the content of `PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL` Please paste the code inline into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The library you're using will only assist you in generating the file to be printed, the print preview behaviour of Chrome is baked into the browser and used to have a flag you could toggle on/off **on a per user/browser basis** but now I believe it has to be disabled via command line. Either way it's not a solution for a customer-facing application.

If it was an internal application and your client was printing off a printer on the local network of an office you could use something like https://github.com/rawilk/laravel-printing to send the file directly to the printer but it doesn't sound like this is the case based on your question.

Comment: yes, i used this laravel printing package. but my requirements are different. I think from browser we can't control the preview of print.